# Would burial in a cemetery skyscraper be accepted?

Tags: halal-haram

Interested to see how something like this:

http://www.theverge.com/2013/12/12/5204974/skyscraper-cemetery-design-in-norway

would be accepted for Muslim burial.  Would burial in such a place be allowed?

Comment: it is just a proposal lets wait until it becomes real. then our scholars will research and tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is available land, the burial should be in earth. But if there is no land available then burial out of earth is accepted. But still the required terms should be met for a dead Muslim:

- No disrespect should be for dead body.
- The grave should not be reopened.
- The smell of expired dead body should not bother the    other people.
- Animals should not have access to dead body.

**Reference:**

The Istifta (asking for Islamic ruling) from [official website of Imam Khamenei](http://leader.ir/)

Comment: can u please provide the direct link to his answer instead of his website home page

Comment: @Zia sorry, the website is not in such a form that have direct link per each fatwa.